# Auto-updating blog of my youtube channel

Tags: youtube, blogs, fetch, auto-update, squarespace

I am interested in building a specific page (I am now using squarespace) that actively updates videos from my youtube channel...

Specifically, I would like the page to fetch new uploads from youtube, and post them in a blog format (with date stamp, etc.) on my website.

Squarespace, says they cannot assist me with outside code...

Would anyone like to guide a beginner in the right direction?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first option I recommend is to use the rss feed block, you can pull an rss feed from your youtube channel, thus your latest video updates will be present on one page:
http://vdo.me/youtube-rss-feed-for-you-channel/

http://www.youtube.com/rss/user/YOURCHANNELNAME/videos.rss

Else you should just embedded each video into a blog post, this is probably the best option cause then you have full control